# Zend2 reuse same view file with pictures

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a controller with two actions what uses the exact same view file (the index.phtml)

If the URL says for example : *localhost/public/map*
Then the URL for the image file is  *localhost/public/style/img.jpg*
But if I use a different action in the same controller then the URL will change to *localhost/public/map/style/img.jpg* what doesn't exist.

Also if I am not using the same template so I have a separate one for choose action, it is doing the exact same thing so it will have the extra "map" word in the URL.

Any idea how could I get this solved?

Example code:

Controller

```
public function indexAction(){
    $view = new ViewModel();
    return $view;

public function chooseAction(){
    $view = new ViewModel();
    $view->setTemplate("map/index"); //will not work with just "index"
    return $view;
}
```

index.phtml

```
<?php
 // module/Map/view/index.phtml:

 $title = 'Map';
 $this->headTitle($title);
?>
<img src="style/img.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply point to the absolute path of the image:

```
<?php
// module/Map/view/index.phtml:

$title = 'Map';
$this->headTitle($title);
?>
<img src="/public/style/img.jpg"/>
```

---

If you want the template to be named index instead of `map/index` you have to change the template name in your `template_map` in the `module.config.php` file in the config folder:

Now probably it looks probably like this:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    //...other things
    'template_map' => array(
        'map/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/index.phtml',
        //...more view templates
    )
)
```

Simply change to 'map/index' to 'index'. Then you can do:

```
$view->setTemplate("index");
```

### Update:

From your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32593531/zend2-reuse-same-view-file-with-pictures/32602020#comment53188411_32602020) I understand that part of the problem is that you don't want to hardcode your folder names. In that case you can always use [the php `__NAMESPACE__` constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.nsconstants.php). This might solve your issue regarding hardcoding paths inside your modules.

If you would later put your site in a folder and you configure everything correctly then using an absolute path to your images should not be a problem.

Comment: If I use absolute path then it will start from the localhost so if i have the site in a folder then that wont work and i dont really want to hardcode the folder name into every controller if i have more than one action.
The problem is not the name of the template. The problem is that if i dont use another action than index then it will take the modules name into the resource's urls just straight after "public".

Comment: With the __NAMESPACE__ it will do the same:
<img src="<?php echo(__NAMESPACE__);?>img/style/map/main.png" usemap="#county"/>
Will result : http://localhost/farm/public/map/img/style/map/main.png.
So it will take the extra "map" between public and img folders.